# Problems installing express using npm.

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Im trying to install express using npm, running this code:

npm install express mongoose jade less expresso

But i keep getting this error,

```
> make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage

sh: make: command not found

npm ERR! expresso@0.9.2 preinstall: `make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage"` failed with 127
npm ERR! Failed at the expresso@0.9.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the expresso package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make deps/jscoverage/node-jscoverage
```

I searched a lot and can't seem to find the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have make, you must install it (it's a part of gcc).

If you're on a Debian-based linux distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

---

If you're on Mac OS X you must install XCode and then install its Command Line Tools:

Install XCode 4 then open it, Got to Preferences -> Downloads -> Components -> Click on Command Line Tools and then click on its Install button.

---

And I just hope you're not on Windows, because I won't be able to help you hehe :-P

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wicked thank you very much for that, got it all working now. A lot of node tuts dont tell you about this. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

What TomShreds said, and you may also want to swap "expresso" for "mocha", which kind of replaced expresso (from expresso's GitHub readme: "Be sure to check out Expresso's successor Mocha.")

Comment: I agree with this, just use Mocha ;-)

Comment: Cheers for the info, ill have a look at that now.